# Replace duplicates in a group with the majority vote in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Pandas dataframe

| image | user | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| img_01 | 1 | 1 |
| img_01 | 2 | 0 |
| img_01 | 2 | 1 |
| img_01 | 2 | 0 |
| img_01 | 3 | 1 |
| img_01 | 4 | 1 |
| img_02 | 1 | 1 |
| img_02 | ... | ... |

As you can see, user 2 gave 3 answers in total for `img_01`, but not always the same. This happens throughout the dataset with different images and users. I know I can acquire the (image/user) combinations of these duplicates with

```
g = dataset.groupby('image')['user'].value_counts()
g = g[g > 1]
```

Now I want to replace his 3 answers with the majority vote among his answers or drop him entirely. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Feels like you may be over complicating it.
I'd just summarise, then take the top one.

```
df.value_counts().reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['sample', 'user']).drop(columns = 0)
```

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: But this replaces the votes of the user the first vote he gave, not the majority vote.